# Printpreview controller does not display the file

Tags: c#, print-preview

I have the codes below

```
fName =E:\Csharp\NewMacaron\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\\data00.txt"
```

From a method within my program I create, into application folder, a series of datas as fName above

After lunching the printing form I have the printcontroller preview on screen with Previous Next and some other buttons for printing and zooming.

On `form_load` I have `ShowPage();`

`PrintPageEventHandler` does not work and nothing is displayed.

However when I click the `print_button` correct page is printed:

What is wrong with the `printpreviewcontroller` ?

I'am using .net 3.5 and c# 2008

```
    private void ShowPage()
    {
        try
        {
            streamToPrint = new StreamReader(fName, Encoding.UTF8);
            pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DocumentName = fName;
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            printFont = new Font("Courier", 10);
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = prnName;     // GetDefaultPrinter returns prName
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("PaperA4", 840, 1180);
            ppc = new PrintPreviewControl();
            ppc.Document = pd;
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message.ToString());
        }
    }


    private void print_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        streamToPrint = new StreamReader(fName, Encoding.UTF8);
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
        try
        {
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message.ToString());
            streamToPrint.Close();
        }
        streamToPrint.Close();
        PublicVariables.PrintFormStat = false;
        PublicVariables.PrintData = 0;
        this.Hide();
```

I have a CRIMINAL BUG in the program the printform was named ppc and the printpreviewcontroller also.

I don't know how assembly has accepted that.

After the correction of that tI can only use one time printpreviewcontroller

The second page is not displayed.

Comment: Yes however what I have to print goes from data00.txt to data99.txt, it depends how many has been created from the database. I put it for saying that the fName is not empty

Comment: I gived up from printpreviewcontroller. I resolved display probleme with ListView.